# Java ProcessBuilder showing console of started java application?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a JAVA application that launches (using ProcessBuilder) another JAVA application like this:

```
String val = "something";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", dir, appName, val);
Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

Now, this works fine, appName is launched with the parameter val and it runs and works ... great ... the problem is no Console Window appears ... appName does a LOT of outputting to the console and we need to see it ... how can I start the process with a console?

I am trying stuff like ("CMD.exe", "java", "-classpath", dir, appName, val), etc... but I can't get it right ...

Also, I can't redirect the streams, my program can actually start 5-10 of these appName's, each should have their own console window showing their own information.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you see a javaw.exe process running in your task manager after you ran this code?

Answer (score 0):

console windows are generally not the most reliable form of logging. they only store a set amount of information (buffer) and can behave differently across platforms.

i strongly suggest logging to a file using something like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) and if you need to see it real time use a [tail like program](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) (i see you're using windows).

in addition to this, seeing as you want the windows visible at all times and launching a tail program for each log might be annoying, i'd write my own log window in java swing.

the basic idea is to not rely on the OS too much.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript java -classpath ...");` ?

Anyway, consider using a logging framwork (log4j, commons-logging), because opening 5 consoles is not the most clever thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I call a few shell scripts via Process to open a command line window and launch whatever I need. As long as the scripts don't detach - you can usually stop any shell command from doing this -java will still hold the running process.

I did it in linux but the concept should be similar.

```
#!/bin/bash
# To open a process in a new window.
gnome-terminal -x ./your-real-shell-script-here.sh "$@"
```

the real script will have your java execution in it, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar your-jar-file.jar "$@"
```

I think you can use javaw to run on windows, so you might only need the one shell script.

Answer (score 0):

**A Console object only exists when you execute java....   from a console.**  Otherwise, the call to obtain one returns null.

If you want to see a console, you need to open a command shell console (e.g. windows cmd.exe or Unix bash shell window) and type:

```
java -classpath="..." com.example.appName arg1
```

If you want to run in a different manner, sorry to say, logging to Console is not for you.  Instead, log using one of:

- log4j
- slf4j
- logback